# TweenMax hover animation issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, gsap

I have a nagivation bar with `li` in my backbone application. I am creating a hover effect for the links. The effect is just a background image sliding to the hovered link and then going back to the original position.

For the animation, I am using `TweenMax` library. The way this works is:

First I initialize `TimelineMax` with a `paused` property like this:

```
this.animation = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });
```

then I work with these methods:

```
prepareToAnimate: function(to) {
   this.animation.to(this.el, .5, { left: to });
   return this;
},
animate: function() {
   this.animation.play();
},
reverse: function() {
   this.animation.reverse();
}
```

So basically, from outside my view I wanted to call `movingElementView.prepareToAnimate(200).animate()` on `mouseenter` and `movingElementView.reverse()` on `mouseleave`.

It is animating, but the animation is going crazy. It goes forward, then it goes backward, then jumps forward again. I checked the `console` and it seems to add up the duration and probably `left` property as well. Do I have to `new` up `TimelineMax` on every mouse event instead?

Comment: can you prepare a fiddle please?

Comment: I actually sorted it out by using `this.animation.clear()` and works perfectly. I will post a fiddle later on today, just in case someone needs to do something similar.

Comment: I am interested in the fiddle just in case there might be a, lets say a cleaner and more flexible solution to this.

Comment: yeah, sure. I will post it soon, I just need to finish up a project in the next hour. :)